# How to Programmatically Split and Manipulate Rows of Data From Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am hoping one of you will be able to help get me started on this issue. I need to create some sort of macro or VBA code to split and manipulate rows of data in Excel.

For this example, we have 5 rows of data. The first 3 rows are item information for Order # 0000000000-00 and the last 2 rows are item information for order # 0000000000-01. I need one row ("HDR") for each order number, and one row ("ITM") for each product per order. I have included an example below showing the data I will receive and the desired outcome.

Raw Data:

```
order-id        product-num     date        buyer-name  product-name    quantity-purchased
0000000000-00   10000000000000  5/29/2014   John Doe    Product 0       1
0000000000-00   10000000000001  5/29/2014   John Doe    Product 1       2
0000000000-00   10000000000002  5/29/2014   John Doe    Product 2       1
0000000000-01   10000000000002  5/30/2014   Jane Doe    Product 2       1
0000000000-01   10000000000003  5/30/2014   Jane Doe    Product 3       1
```

Desired Outcome:

```
HDR 0000000000-00   John Doe    5/29/2014
ITM 10000000000000  Product 0   1
ITM 10000000000001  Product 1   2
ITM 10000000000002  Product 2   1
HDR 0000000000-01   Jane Doe    5/30/2014
ITM 10000000000002  Product 2   1
ITM 10000000000003  Product 3   1
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated!!! Thank you.

Comment: Great first question, +1, especially for adding the desired outcome example, it makes questions like this so much easier to read. Did you try using a Pivot table?

Comment: Thanks, @DaveRook, I appreciate that. Unfortunately, I do not think a Pivot table would work for a few reasons, which made me realize that I probably left out a few important details.

1. This will be a recurring need. This will need to be done possibly every day.

2. There will be a lot more data than what I posted here (rows&columns), including some hard-coded/static values.

3. The end results must be in a spreadsheet format to be exported as a csv.

Comment: I'd suggest using VBA to sort the data on a couple metrics, then checking for matches and writing to a new sheet. Give it a try and let us know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro does what you want, but it's only tested with the data you've given (although if it continues in the same manner, it should be fine, the problem will be if you add more columns, but the code should really be easy to update)

```
Sub SortMeOut()

Dim previousOrderId As String

Dim row As Integer
row = 2


previousOrderId = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

Dim offset As Integer
offset = 0

Do While (True)

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
        End If

    Dim isHeader As Boolean
    isHeader = True
    Do While (True) 'loop through all columns with a match

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value <> previousOrderId Then
        Exit Do
        End If

        If Not isHeader Then
           Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row + 1 + offset).Value = "ITM"
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value ' product num
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & row).Value ' product name
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & row).Value ' quantity
            End If


        If isHeader Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row + offset).Value = "HDR"
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value 'order id
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & row + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & row).Value ' name of the dude
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row).Value ' date

            'we also have to do the first item as well...
             Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row + 1 + offset).Value = "ITM"
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value ' product num
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & row).Value ' product name
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & row).Value ' quantity
            isHeader = False
        End If

      row = row + 1

    Loop

offset = offset + 1
previousOrderId = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value


Loop

End Sub
```

It assumes the data is on workseet1 and spills the results to worksheet2

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Dave! This worked perfectly. I was able to add the additional columns that I needed and it works like a charm.