# How to Programmatically Split Data Using VBA Using Specific Logic

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is an addition to my previous post [here](https://superuser.com/q/762648/328648). The code that was previously supplied to me worked like a charm, but I am having issues modifying it adding some additional logic.

I am creating a macro in VBA to do the following. I have raw order data that I need to transform based on some logic.

Raw Data:

```
order-id      product-num     date      buyer-name  prod-name   qty-purc  sales-tax  freight  order-st
0000000000-00 10000000000000  5/29/2014 John Doe    Product 0   1         1.00       1.50     GA
0000000000-00 10000000000001  5/29/2014 John Doe    Product 1   2         1.00       1.50     GA
0000000000-00 10000000000002  5/29/2014 John Doe    Product 2   1         1.00       2.00     GA
0000000000-01 10000000000002  5/30/2014 Jane Doe    Product 2   1         0.00       0.00     PA
0000000000-01 10000000000003  5/30/2014 Jane Doe    Product 3   1         0.00       0.00     PA
```

Desired Outcome:

```
HDR 0000000000-00   John Doe    5/29/2014
CHG Tax 3.00
CHG Freight  5.00  
ITM 10000000000000  Product 0   1
ITM 10000000000001  Product 1   2
ITM 10000000000002  Product 2   1
HDR 0000000000-01   Jane Doe    5/30/2014
ITM 10000000000002  Product 2   1
ITM 10000000000003  Product 3   1
```

The "CHG" rows are created based on the following logic; if the order-st is CA or GA, add the total of sales-tax and freight for each of the rows with the same order-id. If the order-st is NOT CA or GA, no CHG rows should be created.

Any help would be appreciated - let me know if I left any details out!

Comment: You do need to show your own work next time, to show what you did try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tweaking the solution provided by @DaveRook I have finally figured this out. I am just including the part that I changed which was the If loops that were printing the CHG rows.

```
If totalTax > 0 Then
    offset = offset + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & headerRow + offset).EntireRow.Insert
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & headerRow + offset).Value = "CHG Tax"
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & headerRow + offset).Value = totalTax
End If

If totalFreight > 0 Then
    offset = offset + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & headerRow + offset).EntireRow.Insert
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & headerRow + offset).Value = "CHG Freight"
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & headerRow + offset).Value = totalFreight
End If
```

Basically, the previous version was not accounting for the offset of the values.

Example 1:

[image: order-data-1]
[image: order-reformat-1]

Example 2:

[image: order-data-2]
[image: order-reformat-2]

Comment: Well done for this, +1

Answer (score 1):

This does it but only tested with the details you've provided

```
Sub SortMeOut()

Dim previousOrderId As String

Dim row As Integer
row = 2


previousOrderId = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

Dim offset As Integer
offset = 0

Do While (True)

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
        End If

    Dim isHeader As Boolean
    isHeader = True

   Dim headerRow As Integer
    headerRow = -99 ' be a duff number to test easily

    Dim totalTax As Double
    totalTax = 0

    Dim totalFreight As Double
    totalFreight = 0

    Do While (True) 'loop through all columns with a match

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value <> previousOrderId Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        'Be there a value for the new thingy! If so, accumulate them
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & row).Value = "GA" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & row).Value = "CA" Then
            totalTax = totalTax + Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & row).Value
            totalFreight = totalFreight + Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & row).Value
        End If

        If Not isHeader Then
           Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row + 1 + offset).Value = "ITM"
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value ' product num
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & row).Value ' product name
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & row).Value ' quantity
            End If


        If isHeader Then
        headerRow = row
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row + offset).Value = "HDR"
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value 'order id
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & row + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & row).Value ' name of the dude
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row).Value ' date

            'we also have to do the first item as well...
             Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row + 1 + offset).Value = "ITM"
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value ' product num
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & row).Value ' product name
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row + 1 + offset).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & row).Value ' quantity
            isHeader = False
        End If

      row = row + 1

    Loop


'at this stage we simply insert the values, or at least, we try to. If it goes wrong, then time for tea!

If totalTax > 0 Then
headerRow = headerRow + 1
offset = offset + 1
    Range("A" & headerRow).EntireRow.Insert
    Range("A" & headerRow).Value = "CHG Tax"
    Range("B" & headerRow).Value = totalTax
End If

If totalFreight > 0 Then
    headerRow = headerRow + 1
    offset = offset + 1
    Range("A" & headerRow).EntireRow.Insert
    Range("A" & headerRow).Value = "CHG Freight"
    Range("B" & headerRow).Value = totalFreight
End If

offset = offset + 1
previousOrderId = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value


Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

And after the VBa is run (although I admit, I've had some issues (not fixed) such as the quantity shows as date (?!) but I've manually fixed this for the screen shot).

[image]

Comment: this work if the first order is CA or GA. If the second, third, etc. order is CA or GA then the CHG lines are being populated ABOVE the HDR line.

Raw Data: http://imgur.com/cgAiZW5

Reformatted Data: http://imgur.com/tSoQcTf,kHuUlar#1

Comment: After playing with it, I finally figured it out! I will leave my solution as a separate answer.